# Auto Updating C# Windows Service

Tags: c#

I have a Windows service written in C# running on Windows 10 and 11 machines.

Now I want to add some auto update functionality.
On my research I found Omaha. I could see, that I need a server part for it. But where to obtain a server? Due to some requirements I need to host the update server by myself and not to buy it as a service.

Or is there something else I can use as auto updater?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really broad question and has no real definitive answer to it;

For any "Auto Update" action you would need a "server part" (as you call it) to host your new update. That could be anything really, even a GitHub page would suffice, but not a recommended solution.

If I were in your shoes I'd host a Virtual Machine somewhere with a dedicated (sub-)domain attached to it, so you have full control, but that being said: read on...

You would need to host 2 items: "what version am I currently hosting" and "the version itself" (since you don't want to download a complete service each time you start-up). So the "version" part could just be a simple JSON with a version number, if the current version doesn't match the new number, you might want to download the update and update the application.

But you also mention it's a service. This is not an easy task to auto-update. You can, of course, update the files in the folder where the service is installed (and by that I meant it in the broadest way possible: there is an option not all machines have the same folder) - and you cannot update a file which is "currently used" - which for services is actually almost always. So you'd first need to stop your service, update the files and restart after updating. With (also a bit of a task) the option to rollback if the changes fail (otherwise no service at all to start).

I would suggest *not* looking into Omaha since it's C based and not C# based (as you tagged your question), it would lead you into a world of hurt where you assume C and C# are alike (but far from the truth in most cases).
Besides the C and C# thing - Omaha acts like a Service on itself, which is a good thing, but most likely not what you're looking for - do you want the "second update service" to search for new versions every x time or do you want to control this flow (without user intervention).

I know this has raised more questions than it is an answer, but if I were you I'd reconsider the "what" "how" and "if" parts before I'd create an auto-update-thingy for "just 11 machines" (not to be condescending - not at all)